# Does OL3 support KMZ

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

How to process KMZ file in Openlayers 3. Is there any way then please tell me.

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: new ol.source.KML({
              extractStyles: true,
              projection: 'EPSG:3857',
              url: 'http://www.spc.noaa.gov/products/watch/ActiveWW.kmz'
            }),
          style: styleFunction
        });
```

Comment: please put some research here

Comment: Simple: No. KMZ are in fact like zip-Files. You need to unpack them first. But since they could contain "nested" Links (to other KML/KMZ) it's maybe easier to use another Format.